# Java JMenu Incorrectly Rendering Twice

Tags: java, swing, paint, paintcomponent, jmenu

Thanks for any help that can be provided. Here's the overview of my problem:

I decided to dip my toes into the fun waters of graphics rendering and make a basic "paint" program. In doing so I wanted to add a menu bar, as most programs have. However, this menu bar is rendering itself twice, once where it works and is clickable, and the second being only a ghost image that cannot be interacted with.

Here's a picture of the program without me having clicked anything: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9wxd.png]

This is after anything gets updated onscreen: 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVZWB.png]

The circled "File" button does not work at all. The other one, however, does.
I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, so here is the code I used to make this small program (pardon the comments, those were for my own benefit):

```
package painter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
//This class will do the job of bringing together all the various sub-    classes and rendering everything.
public class MainPainterGUI extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel menuPanel;

    private JMenuBar menuBar;

    //These values are going to be used to set an initial window size.
    private final short WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1000;   
    private final short WINDOW_WIDTH = 1000;

    //This constructor will do the actual creation of the window.
    public MainPainterGUI()
    {
        //This does the same thing that setTitle does.
        super("Painter");
        //setTitle("Painter");

        //This method will set what the window is supposed to do when the red x is clicked.
        //Technically, the value passed is an integer.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Obviously this method sets the initial size of the window.  It can be changed by the user however.
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        //This method sets the center of the window relative to whatever is passed.  In this case, null makes
        //the window appear in the center of the desktop regardless of the size.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        menuPanel = new JPanel();

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menuBar.add(new FileMenu());

        menuPanel.add(menuBar);

        //The add method simply attaches a component to whatever is calling, like a frame or another panel.
        //The BorderLayout is needed to use the draggable toolbar.
        add(new PaintPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //This will allow the window to be seen.  Make sure this method is last, as if 
        //a component is created afterwards it may not be visible.
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here's the FileMenu class:

```
package painter;

import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;


public class FileMenu extends JMenu
{
    JMenuItem newFile, open, save, saveAs;

    public FileMenu()
    {
        super("File");

        newFile = new JMenuItem("New...");
        open = new JMenuItem("Open...");
        save = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveAs = new JMenuItem("Save As...");

        add(newFile);
        add(open);
        addSeparator();
        add(save);
        add(saveAs);
    }

}
```

And here is the PaintPanel class:

```
package painter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel implements MouseInputListener
{
    //These two values will be used to determine where the mouse is and thus where to paint...stuff...
    public int xCoordinate, yCoordinate = -10;

    public PaintPanel()
    {
        //These two methods simply attaches the mouse listener methods listed below to the actual panel.
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    //This method is an overwritten version of the default paint method.  It's job is to render custom graphics
    //objects on the screen.  The Graphics g argument is the item responsible for doing the actual rendering.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
         g.setColor(Color.black);
         g.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 10, 10);
    }

    @Override
    //This method, added because of the MouseInputListener implementation, is used when a user clicks the left mouse button.
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        xCoordinate = e.getX();
        yCoordinate = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    //This method, added because of the MouseInputListener implementation, is used when a user presses and holds the
    //left mouse button while moving the mouse.
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        xCoordinate = e.getX();
        yCoordinate = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I have tried adding "super.paintComponent(g);" to the start of the paintComponent() method, but while that fixes the problem, it only creates a worse one. It simply renders one black square that follows my mouse around.

Update: Just to help others out, here's a summary of what has been suggested and tried by me at the time of writing this.

Sidenote-In the meantime I have been working on other parts of the program, so you may notice a "tools" menu at the top now that wasn't previously there.  However, since it doesn't affect the current problem at all, there's no need to provide the updated code.

As suggested by Andrew Thompson, changing PaintPanel's paintComponent method to the include a call to the super's paint method results in the following picture:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.setColor(currentColor);
     g.fillRect(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 10, 10);
}
```

Everything is rendering correctly, except now all the drawing is being deleted except for the current single black square.
[image]

falijbour's (see his answer below as there are quite a few changes) suggestion worked slightly better except anytime the panel needs to be updated (like from being minimized or the file menu dropping down) it deletes the painted progress.

Here's a couple pictures to clarify:

This is the initial drawing.
[image]

This is after clicking "File"
[image]

This is a partial solution, but as clarified by faljbour, you would need to save the coordinates of the pixels and redraw them upon the window being updated.  This however, proves to be extremely challenging with anything other than a single color, pen size, pen shape, and no text.

Comment: `public class FileMenu extends JMenu`  Don't extend classes unless adding or changing functionality.  The `PaintPanel` seems to be the only one that *does* change functionality.

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
         g.setColor(Color.black);` **should be** `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    { super.paintComponent(g);
         g.setColor(Color.black);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson In reply to your first comment, the reason I made panel classes and menu classes was to make it easier to organize everything.  Rather than having one huge class that does all this.  I had seen other people make panels and button classes before, so I thought it would be ok.  In reagrds to adding "super.paintComponent(g);  I had tried that, but now it doesn't paint anything.  It just has a little black square that follows my cursor.  However, the dual "File" menu is gone.

Comment: *"..the reason I made panel classes and menu classes was to make it easier to organize everything."*  Just because something is in a different class, doesn't mean it has to extend the component it is creating..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Two things.  First, I am perfectly willing to change the classes, but why exactly is extending components like I did a bad thing?  I thought it would make it easier, but I would certainly like to know why it's bad to do that for the future.  Secondly, do you have a fix for the fact the fact that adding "super.paintcComponent(g)" deletes all previous drawings?